# Can Jinns shape-shift into Prophets/Messengers?

Tags: jinn

If Jinns can shape-shift into almost anything and everything, can they shape shift to people such as Prophets/Messengers like Esa, Suleiman, Muhammad, etc (Peace be upon them)

Answer (score 2):

Jinn cannot appear like the Prophet Muhammad (SAW):

> The Prophet said: "Whoever sees me in a dream will see me in his wakefulness, and **Satan cannot imitate me in shape**." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/12))

I don't know about other prophets. I don't think there is an explicit hadith.